# VMWare Player fails after installing Docker

Tags: docker, vmware-player, credentials-manager, docker-swarm

Not sure if this is just my issue, but after I have installed Docker on my Machine, when I try to launch my VM i get the following:

> "VMware Player can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard"

the procedures to fix this, break Docker, and vice versa.

There is anything I am missing out? 
I wanna run Docker inside the VM as well to build a Swarm to communicate with my host, but without overcome this issue I am unable to do it.

Comment: Have you tried running both as an administrator?

Answer (score 0):

VMware doesn't like other virtualizations running beside it. I had that "VMware Player can be run after disabling Device/Credential Guard" error a while ago. After wasting a lot fo time searching for a solution, I figured that I had to disable the "Windows Sandbox" feature. Can't have both sadly.